# $(document).ready malfunction, $(document).resize works - same handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a dynamic hero with bootstrap and jQuery. The hero is a banner with a quote and a background image. The issue I am running into is when the quotes exceed a certain length, the text disappears as the total height of the children elements exceeds that of the container div. I have used jQuery to attach a document.ready and document.resize handler, which calculates the height of all the children and resizes the container div appropriately:

```
function getHeights() {
    let childVertOffset = $("#client-hero-child").offset().top;
    let childHeightTotal = 0;

    let children = $("[id=client-hero-child]");
    children.each(function () {
        childHeightTotal += ($(this).outerHeight());
    });

    return childHeightTotal + childVertOffset;
}


function fixContainerHeight(newHeight) {
    $("#client-hero").height(newHeight)
}
```

I attach document.ready and resize handlers to the page as follows:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname.includes('clients/')) {
        fixContainerHeight(getHeights())
    }
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname.includes('clients/')) {
        fixContainerHeight(getHeights())
    }
});
```

The document.resize handler works perfectly, but the issue I'm having is that the document.ready handler seems to be firing before all the content has loaded correctly. The resizing is always off by a consistent amount (calculating the height of the children about 80px less than the resize handler does). What is more interesting is that when I duplicate the document.ready statement, the code works correctly (hints that the function fires too soon), but if I add the document.ready function to a setTimeout function, it doesn't work, which indicates the contrary.

It works if I do the following and duplicate the handler (maybe an issue with the function firing before the content has loaded?):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname.includes('clients/')) {
        fixContainerHeight(getHeights())
    }
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname.includes('clients/')) {
        fixContainerHeight(getHeights())
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    fixContainerHeight(getHeights())
},100);
```

The html (erb) is as follows:

```
  <div class="row" id="client-hero-child">
    <div class="col-12 px-sm-0">
      <%= image_tag(@case.logo.url, class: "float-left testimonial-logo") %>
    </div>
    <div class="category-description">
      <p class="left-align client-text"><%= @case.category %></p>
    </div>
    <p class="client-text">"<%= @case.quote.html_safe %>"</p>
    <div class="col-12 pt-3" id ="client-hero-child">
      <span class="float-right client-text"><%= @case.quotee %></span><br/>
      <span class="float-right quote-position" style="margin-bottom: 15px"><%= @case.quotee_position %></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Update:

After some troubleshooting and console logging, I figured out that the issue is related to a CSS feature - I have the following css:

```
#client-hero {
  height: 520px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  .banner_detail_height {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
  }
```

The 'top' property is causing the trouble, this seems to occur a split second after the page loads. This explains why the duplicated code fixes the issue. The first time the load handler runs, it calculates the vert offset as 110px, then the css is run, adding a 20% top margin, then the handler runs a 2nd time, and calculates a vert offset of 200px.

Is there a way to ensure the styling is run prior to the handler?

Comment: Consider listening to the load event instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: Tried that, same issue - doesn't correctly calculate the height of the child elements, then if I resize even a tiny amount (increase screen by 1px) everything is correctly calculated and formatted. What is interesting is that, if I duplicate the code and add some console logs, I can see that it is the vertical offset that is being incorrectly calculated:
First time the onload runs:
vert offset: 101.58 px
child heights: 1073.91 px

Second time onload runs:
vert offset: 213.02 px
child heights: 1073.91 px

So the issue is definately related to the vertical offset and order of events.

Comment: Are you loading images or fonts after the page has loaded?

Comment: What if you set your `setTimeout` to something larger, like `10000`.  100ms isn't very long if it's still waiting to load content.

Comment: Note that doc.ready runs **when the DOM is ready**, *not* when the page has finished loading / when all the "content" has loaded.  You may need to add additional even handlers to your images etc.

Comment: From https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ you may want to try `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` (which is believe is also the first comment above)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments. Tried the $( window ).on('load') approach, same problem. Please see the update in my OP, the issue is due to a css top property occuring too slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the issue, it was due to the **$(window).on('load')** function running before the CSS 'top' property was applied. By changing the css 'top' to 'padding', it seemed to affect the order of the events and is the css is run before the onLoad handler.